Infinite Loop on RNEventSource with Server-Sent Events (SSE) - Only Receiving “attempt: 1”
I am working on a React Native expo managed project using RNEventSource to handle Server-Sent Events (SSE). My backend is correctly streaming data (confirmed via Postman), but the frontend gets stuck in an infinite loop of the same response, only receiving:
LOG  Open SSE connection.
LOG  Stream Data: {"attempt": 1, "run_id": "1efb7463-0ff8-60c3-bd10-17ccc210899f"}
WARN  Unexpected Data: {"run_id":"1efb7463-0ff8-60c3-bd10-17ccc210899f","attempt":1}
LOG  Stream Data: {"attempt": 1, "run_id": "1efb7463-0ff8-60c3-bd10-17ccc210899f"}
WARN  Unexpected Data: {"run_id":"1efb7463-0ff8-60c3-bd10-17ccc210899f","attempt":1"}
...

Sent the exact same data I'm attempting on the front in the backend also tried with Postman that worked fine.
  const askDogy = async (request) => {
  const url = `${assitantBaseUrl}/threads/${threadId}/runs/stream`
  const requestBody = JSON.stringify({
    assistant_id: assistantID,
    input: {
      messages: [{ role: 'user', content: request }],
    },
    stream_mode: ['messages'],
  })

  const options = {
    body: requestBody,
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      Accept: 'text/event-stream',
    },
  }

  eventSourceRef.current = new RNEventSource(url, options)

  eventSourceRef.current.addEventListener('open', () => {
    console.log('Open SSE connection.')
  })

  eventSourceRef.current.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
    console.log('Raw Event:', event)
    try {
      const data = JSON.parse(event.data)
      console.log('Parsed Data:', data)

      if (data.content) {
        console.log('AI Reply Content:', data.content)
        setChatResponse('Bot', data.content, true)
      } else {
        console.warn('Unexpected Data:', data)
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error parsing event data:', error)
    }
  })

  eventSourceRef.current.addEventListener('error', (error) => {
    console.error('Stream error:', error)

        if (error.status === 409) {
          console.log('Conflict detected, creating a new thread...')
          // Create a new thread and retry
          tempThreadId = await createThread()
          if (!tempThreadId)
            throw new Error('Failed to create a new thread after conflict')
          setThreadId(tempThreadId)

          // Retry the stream with the new thread ID
          console.log('Retrying with new thread ID:', tempThreadId)
          await askDogy(request) // Recursive call with the new thread
        } else {
          handleStopStream()
        }
  })
}

Debugging Observations:

I receive the same attempt: 1 data repeatedly with no progress.
The backend should send incremental updates, but the frontend logs do not show progress.

Questions:

Is there a known issue with RNEventSource or its compatibility with
React Native?
Could there be something specific I need to handle in
RNEventSource to parse incremental updates?
Any other npm package/library I can use to handle server sent events in react native/expo?

Things I've tried:

Verified backend compliance with the SSE spec.
Ensured RNEventSource initialization includes proper headers and method.
Added maximum retries and timeout logic in case of backend failures (now removed).
Tested backend with Postman and it streams correctly.

